# Why accuracy doesn't get printed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

So the following code never prints the accuracy.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 
  3 """.
  4     This is the code to accompany the Lesson 2 (SVM) mini-project.
  5 
  6     Use a SVM to identify emails from the Enron corpus by their authors:....
  7     Sara has label 0
  8     Chris has label 1
  9 """
 10 ....
 11 import sys
 12 from time import time
 13 sys.path.append("../tools/")
 14 from email_preprocess import preprocess
 15 from sklearn import svm
 16 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 17 
 18 
 19 ### features_train and features_test are the features for the training
 20 ### and testing datasets, respectively
 21 ### labels_train and labels_test are the corresponding item labels
 22 features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = preprocess()
 23 clf=svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
 24 clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
 25 pred=clf.predict(features_test)
 26 print(accuracy_score(labels_test, pred))
```

I am trying to find out why line `print(accuracy_score(labels_test, pred))` does not print anything at all. It should print some value. What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console when running the script?

Comment: What value do you expect it to print?

Comment: Calm down. Was just trying to get quick information about issue you are facing.

Comment: ^refers to people who have voted to close the question. @vcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line of code which makes it print something. I have seen people using 1000 iterations normally:

```
clf=svm.SVC(kernel='linear',max_iter=100)
```